# Characteristic polynomial of the matrix $(a_i\cdot b_j)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ be two real vectors.
Then the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $(a_i\cdot b_j)_{i,j=1\ldots n}$ is 
$$\chi(x) = x^{n}- \left<a,b\right>\cdot{}x^{n-1}.$$

Does anyone have a short proof of this result? Or, even better, a reference to it? I have a proof, but I find it clumsy.

Answer (score 3):

Denote your matrix by $A$. Then:

1. Show that any vector orthogonal to $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue equal to $0$. How many such linearly independent vectors do we have?
2. Show that $a$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. What is the corresponding eigenvalue?
3. Combine previous two results.

Comment: Answer to the question in 2: The eigenvalue is $\left<a,b\right>\cdot$. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @AnnyOne Right. You thus know all roots of the characteristic polynomial. P.S. You are welcome.